# LINQ/Lambda .OrderBy(Date Type).ThenBy(Enum Type)

Tags: c#, linq, enums, lambda

I have the following code:

```
transactionBindingSource.DataSource = context.Transactions
                .Where(t => t.Date >= BeginningDate &&
                        t.Date <= EndDate)
                .OrderBy(t => t.Date)
                .ThenBy(t => t.TransactionType)
                .ToList();
```

This is a transaction list.  I want to order the transactions first by Date and then by the type.  The type is an enum that I have created.  The enum can by Deposit or Withdrawal.

Enum code:

```
enum CashFlowTransactionType
{
    Deposit = 10,
    Withdrawal = 20
}
```

When I get my datagrid from this list it orders by date and then transaction type, but it puts Withdrawal before Deposit.  I need the Deposits to post before the Withdrawal.  I thought that it would sort it by the enum value, which is why I made deposit 10 and Withdrawal 20.  This doesn't seem to be the case though.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. I'd expect this to be fine. (What does this look like in the database? Do you have the same enum values there in your tables? What does the log look like?)

Comment: Is `Date` a `DateTime` field?  Is there a time component that is affecting the results?

Comment: That value is showing up as integers in the database.  It works as expected when I use OrderBy(t => t.TransactionType).  Does ThenBy() have different limitations?

Comment: It is a DateTime field, you could definitely be right.

Comment: @Safari137 What exactly is in the database? If it's full date time's then what are you seeing is expected. Perhaps `.OrderBy(t=>d.Date.Date)` would work?

Comment: Closing as the question as off topic because *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and **the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.**"* The code presented [does not reproduce the problem](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BOvWe8). Are you sure there is no time component to your dates you are retrieving, if the times where not the same it would not care about the order of the enum.

Comment: It was the DateTime field.  I removed all the times and change my code to leave times out on new transactions.  Thank you!

Comment: @Safari137 please do not just abandon this question as a question with no accepted answer. Either post your own answer and mark it accepted or delete the question (but I don't think you will be able to delete because answers received upvotes).

Comment: @ScottChamberlain The question cannot be deleted because there are multiple answers.  None of the answers have a positive score, so if any of the answers were the only answer, the question could be deleted.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I have to wait 2 days to accept my own answer.  I'll take care of it though.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was resolved by removing the time portion of the Date property.

Answer (score 0):

Define your enum as :

```
public enum CashFlowTransactionType : int
{
    Deposit = 10,
    Withdrawal = 20
}
```

then call it as :

```
transactionBindingSource.DataSource = context.Transactions
            .Where(t => t.Date >= BeginningDate && t.Date <= EndDate)
            .OrderBy(t => t.Date)
            .ThenBy(t => (int)t.TransactionType)
            .ToList();
```

Comment: The `: int` here isn't required - that's the default underlying type.

Comment: This isn't going to change anything.  When comparing enums, the underlying integer value is what is compared.  Extracting out the underlying numeric value isn't going to change that.

Comment: Why this could help?